# Margin behavior in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am having trouble understanding the behavior of margins (`android:layout_margin*`) when used in ConstraintLayout. Margins seem to only take effect in certain situations, and I am hoping someone can explain it to me (or confirm that it's a ConstraintLayout bug).

I have the following layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
         android:id="@+id/leftView"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightView"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

     <View
         android:id="@+id/rightView"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

... which produces the following output...

[image: Expected Output]

However, when I change the margin from the `leftView` to the `rightView`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/leftView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rightView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

... the margin unexpectedly disappears...

[image: Unexpected Output]

Can someone explain whether this is expected behavior and, if so, why that is?

Comment: Curious: what happens if you additionally move `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightView"` to `rightView`, via `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftView"`?

Comment: @stkent Almost the same behavior as in the second case. But in this case the `LeftView` fills up the entire width of the screen unless `LayoutWidth` is set to some value like `100dp`. I don't understand the behavior either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `leftview` is depend on `rightview`, so you can set margin of `leftview` to `rightview`.

When a view have margin, it means the view is giving space **TO WHICH VIEW IS DEPENDING ON**.

if you write `android:layout_marginStart="20dp"` in `rightview`, it will not give space to `leftview` because `rightview` is not **DEPENDING** to `leftview`.

Comment: Thanks. This was probably the clearest and most succinct explanation to the problem.

Comment: Yet, it is not very intuitive. I have a view to which I want to set margin = 20dp,  the bottom margin is not applied because object bellow has a constraint to be positioned bellow that view. Before constraintLayout it was pretty natural to asume that margin was part of a view space.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `rightView` depends on its parent(`ConstraintLayout`), you set up:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

The `parent` is `ConstraintLayout`. You did that you made the `rightView` was on the top-right of its parent(`ConstraintLayout`)

So you used `android:layout_marginStart="20dp"` in the `rightView`. The `rightView` will margin left `20dp` with its parent(`ConstraintLayout`). So there is no white space in this case.

---

The second case is different with the first case. Looks at the `leftView`:

The `leftView` is always on the left side of the `rightView` because you used `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightView"` in the `leftView`

**AND** the `leftView` also depends on its parent(ConstraintLayout) because you used bellow code in the `leftView`

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

**AND** you used `android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"` in the `leftView` that's mean the `leftView` will margin right `20dp` with the `rightView`. So there is white space in this case.

---

You can try to use `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` for the `leftView` you will see a different.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you are looking for, you need to build a `chain`. A chain is correctly defined if all links between the components of the chain are defined.

In your code, `rightView` must be connected to `leftView`. Add the following constraint to `rightView`

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftView"
```

and change the existing `layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf` constraint in leftView to

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toLefttOf="@+id/rightView"
```